# How to run a process(Task) remotely and wait for it to finish?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I have created a simple "job scheduler" specific to my needs. It looks for job specs written to a file, and then starts multiple tasks to run jobs in parallel.

It waits for each task to finish before checking if there are more jobs to be completed.

This works very well for me, but I would now like to use a second server to run some of the jobs. Is there a way to start a job on a remote machine AND somehow receive notification of when it has finished? I know WMI is an option, but wondered if WMI (or something else) would fit easily in to the structure below.

Here is how I do it (very simplified) on a single machine:

```
List<Taskdata> TaskList = new List<Taskdata>();
string[] JobsToAdd = GetListFromSomewhere();

 foreach (var jobString in JobsToAdd)
 {
       var LastTask = new Task(RunProc, jobString);
       LastTask.Start();
       TaskList.Add(new Taskdata(LastTask, DateTime.UtcNow));
 }


if (TaskList.Any())
{
       Task.WaitAny(TaskList.Select(x => x.Task).ToArray());
}




public void RunProc(object state)
{
            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = Path.Combine(@"H:\Projects\Simulator\Simulator\bin\Debug\", "Simulator001.exe"),
                    Arguments = (string)state,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                    CreateNoWindow = false
                }
            };
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: is process close it self whwen finished? if then, make a thread, check process, and if process disappeared, throws message.

Comment: WaitAny() is very convenient. I am looking for something similar across remote machines

Comment: use RPC (remote procedure call) approach . Call procedure ,which will create task and return message to you when task has been completed, remotely .